# How to include and set launch screen status bar color?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, storyboard, launch-screen

I'm new to launch screens in ios 8/9. I've created one (`LaunchScreen.storyboard`) and added a navigation bar with a background color. I want to have the status bar included and colored the same color.

Usually I take screenshots on the individual simulator devices with the status bar present and the text hidden. I've read some resources [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/) and [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html), but this isn't covered. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Go to project target setting
set `statusbarstyle:gray`

and also set in appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    // For change Statusbar Color ios 9.0
    application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the status bar in the launch screen, add following property in info.plist

> Status bar is initially hidden NO

For XML editors ~ add to first  child of

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<false/>
```

It will show with the same background color as the navigation bar.